# Debugger hangs when reaching to Float or Delay

Tags: c, stm32, embedded, debugging, stm32l

When I run this code, the debugger hangs once it reaches to a Float (in this case the variable 'Distance') or Delay, I mean it seems like it's processing, however it never goes through, and I have to close it and run the debugger again, which hangs of course again. Note that the code builds without errors or warnings.
The following is the related part of the code:

```
    void Delay(int x){
    //input milliseconds, delay that number of milliseconds
    int a,b;
    for(a=0; a<x; a++){
        for(b=0; b<1000; b++){
        }
    }
}

int main(void){

                float Distance;     // actual distance in cm
                .
                .
                .

    while(1){

        TIM4_Echo_Read();

    Distance = (timespan / 58.0);

        if (Distance <= 100){

            GPIOB->BSRRL = (1<<7);
        }
            else {
            GPIOB->BSRRH = (1<<7);

            }   
                Delay(10);
        }
```

Any idea why?

Comment: You don't seem be to be certain where it gets stuck. When you put a breakpoint on `Distance` and step over, do you get a value for `Distance`? If you put a breakpoint inside `Delay` on the one of the `for` loops does it get hit?

Comment: @DigitalNinja No, although timespan gets a value. furthermore, it hangs again when it reaches to the next instruction [ if (Distance <= 100) ]. Note that it doesn't hang when I change it from Float to int at the declaration.

Comment: Okay. Is `timespan` a float?

Comment: @DigitalNinja no it's not, just int. and it's initialized as a global variable

Comment: Okay, try changing it to a float or just typecast it like this... `Distance = ((float)timespan/58.0);` Then try running it again.

Comment: just tried the [Distance = ((float)timespan/58.0);] and it still gets stuck. I tried with and without breakpoints. note that I haven't changed the global declaration and kept it as int, since it is used in another function within an equation.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens when you just hardcode `Distance`to have a value of say 100.0, instead of doing the calculation?... `Distance = 100.0; // (timespan / 58.0);`Will you rebuild and try that please?

Comment: just tried it. the debugger was able to move forward, and Distance took the value of 100. However...strangely, it got stuck right on the next instruction [if (Distance <= 100){]

Comment: btw, none of this happens when I declare Distance as int instead of float. however I need an accurate value so I still need that float

Comment: Right, that's why I wanted you to run these tests because it seems like a data type issue with either the MCU or compiler. Leave the hardcoded `Distance`assignment, and change the `if` statement to compare to `100.0`. `if(Distance <= 100.0)`... rebuild and try that.

Comment: Get *OUT* of C and switch to assembly with your debugger. My guess (and it is nothing but a totally random guess from exactly 10 seconds reading this stuff here), is that a function is called that you cannot see in the C code but which would be *abundantly obvious* if you were in assembly. And that code is killing the debugger (by perhaps not returning.) If in assembly mode, you could step into that function and at least find out. (If you are uncomfortable with the assembly code generated by a C compiler, you really need to work on that. I don't think it's an optional skillset.)

Comment: @DigitalNinja tried it, but it still stucks at if(Distance <= 100.0);

Comment: @jonk yes I'm really not used to the assembly code generated by C compiler. I'll try though

Comment: @lightworks You need to develop that skill. Use this as your motivation to move forward. I consider it unacceptable for an embedded C programmer (claiming the name) to be unable to hand-generate assembly code from C for a generalized target ALU. They must also understand what a function prologue and epilogue is, what an activation (frame) record is, and what purposes it serves and may optionally serve, and how compilers allocate registers, etc. They should be able to grab docs, very quickly navigate to the specific details of the specific compiler for a specific CPU, too. This is your moment!

Comment: Interesting... If it _always_ works when `Distance` is an int, then you may need to take jonk's advice and dig deeper.

Comment: I'll take your advice. but for now I need to get this working, I guess i'll use int for the time being. I have a bigger problem with the overall code, which I'm going to post it in a new question. Thank you both

Comment: Maybe a silly suggestion: Did you try 58.0f instead of 58.0 ? I'm pretty sure that 58.0 is seen as double and it will be truncated to float by compiler in your case. But jusy give it a try.

Comment: What is the size of your stack?  Is that enough?  Increase the stack size and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: Is this a Cortex-M4F with floating point hardware?  Are you using the floating point hardware or is it linking with a software library to perform the floating point calculations?  Is the floating point hardware unit enabled?

Comment: @RohatKılıç A compiler will "see" 58.0 as a double (whatever it is on the machine) and 58.0f as a float (which may be the same.) However, it's allowed implicit conversions when (1) mismatched operand types; or, (2) function argument type doesn't match; or, (3) when initializing variables or assigning values to them. And I don't see the definition of *timespan* nor of *Distance*, and I don't know what the compiler is using for float and double (same, or not?), so the question of truncation is probably unknown given what we have here at this time. I'd suspect a type-based intrinsic function.

Comment: It would seem that STM32L4 is a Cortex M4 with FPU. The rest of the family members do not have a FPU. Using floating point variables on a MCU without FPU is always plain wrong and very bad engineering. It seems quite unlikely that you need them too... why are you using centimeter as an internal unit of your program? That too suggests bad design. Use a raw data type similar to the one used by your sensor and only scale to centimeter just before displaying the result to the user.

Comment: Note to other readers here on EE.SE: FYI the same question has been duplicated [on the Keil forums here](http://www.keil.com/forum/62834/debugger-hangs-on-float-instruction/), where more information has been supplied.

Comment: @Lundin `STM32L4 is a Cortex M4 with FPU. The rest of the family members do not have a FPU.` can you proof your very strange theory

Comment: @PeterJ [The ARM manual](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.set.cortexm/index.html) and [ST product info](http://www.st.com/en/microcontrollers/stm32-ultra-low-power-mcus.html?querycriteria=productId=SC2157).

Comment: @Lundin and those links (especially  the ARM one - I do not see ant STM uC there) say that the only L4 family has the FPU? Other STM micros do not? I know couple of other families with the same core STM32F4, STM32F3 ... with hundreds models. All fitted with FPUs.

Comment: @PeterJ This is specifically about the L family. ST uses a very peculiar part number system which does apparently not necessarily correspond to what core the particular device is using.

Comment: @Lundin But you wrote that the **only** L4 family has the FPU. It is misleading not true information.they correspond if you know how to understand the symbols.  I think you just googled it before comment. Did you ever used STM ones?

Comment: @PeterJ Just see the ST link I provided. It is all there. L4 is a member of the L family.

Comment: Now if the OP could specify exactly which part number that is used, we wouldn't have to guess.

Comment: @Lundin - "Now if the OP could specify exactly which part number that is used" - Hi, FYI at their duplicate thread on the Keil forum that I gave in my [earlier comment](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/322780/debugger-hangs-when-reaching-to-float-or-delay#comment754880_322780), the OP has stated that they are using the [**STM32L1**](http://www.st.com/en/microcontrollers/stm32l1-series.html) (Cortex-M3). HTH.

Comment: @SamGibson Ok then indeed it seems that I'm correct and the OP has no clue about what they are doing.

Comment: @Lundin Sorry that I forgot to mention the model/part number, It is STM32L152RC. p.s. If I knew what I'm doing I wouldn't go around asking for explanation, which is perfectly fine as part of learning process, and will keep doing that whenever I get stuck. thanks anyway

Comment: Basically, if your project needs to do advanced math such as trigonometry, integrals, AI etc, float numbers will be convenient to use. You should then, upon starting the project, pick a suitable MCU which comes with a FPU. If your rationale for using float is "I must display decimals to the user" or "my internal unit is centimeters rather than raw values", then you don't need to use float numbers and should get rid of them. Float numbers are problematic because of inaccuracy and they are also incredibly slow if you don't have a FPU. When you have the option, always use integers instead.

Comment: @Lundin Thanks Lundin, I will surely consider that in future projects.